# Load CSV in Spark with types in non standard format

Tags: csv, parsing, apache-spark, schema, apache-spark-dataset

I've got a csv file that I want to read with Spark, specifying a schema to get the types I need. Something like that:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = sqlContext.read()
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("myCsvFilePath.csv");
```

But in my csv file some columns are recorded in a non-standard way, for example double values uses comma as decimal separator or datetime values are strings formatted as dd.MM.yyyy.
Is it possible to define such schema? Or I should read this columns as strings and then parse them explicitly?

Comment: i will suggest to do the file cleansing before feeding to scala . It will be easy and will make sure there is no garbage separator in file .

Comment: please provide some sample of your data

Comment: "10655",31.10.2017,"851869631,35","906126633,45","473","860"
"10425",25.03.2017,"1184646465,14","2090611791,58","13467","37114"

Comment: I'll go with what @ArmonRotemGalOz suggested. Read everything as a string and fix it. You can't apply a partial schema on while reading unfortunately. We all went thru this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the odd formats to standard ones is part of the dataprep pipeline you'd want to use spark for - so yes read these columns as strings and then using either built-in functions or udf you can replace columns with fixed ones (e.g. using withColumn)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.withColumn("fixed_date",unix_timestamp(col("date_column"),"dd.MM.YYYY")).withColumn("fixed_double",regexp_replace(col("double_column"),",",".").cast("double"))
```

Comment: Is there any built-in functions in spark for parsing Date and Double? Or I should provide udf wrapping SimpleDateFormat / DecimalFormat?

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
and you can use unix_timestamp to convert the date and regex_replace to remove commas and then cast to double to convert the doubles.